# If textbox contains <br> tags then condition should be false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If textbox contains `<br>` tags then condition should be false

```
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(notificationTextEnrolmentFeeSection))
    {
        if (notificationTextEnrolmentFeeSection != "<br>") {
            <table class="reports-table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive page-break-after-avoid">
                <tr class="rowPrint">
                    <th>
                        <div class="font-bold letter-spacing">Fee Section</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="rowPrint">
                        <td>
                            <div> @Html.Raw(notificationTextEnrolmentFeeSection)</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is unclear. elaborate little more about your issue.

Comment: when textbox contains <br> or <br/> tag then not go inside the if condition

Comment: I don't advice, but you can do: `if(notificationTextEnrolmentFeeSection.IndexOf("<br>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == -1 && notificationTextEnrolmentFeeSection.IndexOf("<br />", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == -1)`. Note that adding a single space can skip this check.

Answer (score 0):

Use `contains` function to find 'br' tag in the string.

Replace

```
 if (notificationTextEnrolmentFeeSection != "<br>")
```

with

```
 if (notificationTextEnrolmentFeeSection.Contains("<br>") == true)
```

Comment: Use multiple condition in if  `if (x.Contains("<br>") == true && x.Contains("</br>") == true)`

Comment: It's working on my Console. I am attaching the link `https://dotnetfiddle.net/3UJhYQ`

Comment: This should be `false` not `true`.

Comment: Make it not equal to... `if (x.Contains("<br>") != true || x.Contains("</br>") != true)`